# How to save an input variable that can be updated later in Python?

Tags: python, csv, variables, input

In Python, how can you set an input variable that can be accessed later?

If you wanted to set an input variable "minutes_studied" and update it on a daily basis to keep a running total, what is the easiest way to do this?

I am thinking that I may have to write it to a CSV file on each input, but I am wondering if there is a more convenient way?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want persistent data (data that lives after execution), you always need some external storages like file or database

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.